# C++ private variable scoping rules

Tags: c++, scoping

Here is the interface

```
template <class Type>
class stackADT
{
public:
    virtual void initializeStack() = 0;
    virtual bool isEmptyStack() const = 0;
    virtual bool isFullStack() const = 0;
    virtual void push(const Type& newItem) = 0;
    virtual Type top() const = 0;
    virtual void pop() = 0;
    virtual void reverseStack(stackType<Type>& otherStack) = 0;
private:
    int maxStackSize;
    int stackTop;
    Type *list;
};
```

Here is the reverse stack method which is part of class stackType which extends stackADT

```
template <class Type>
class stackType : public stackADT<Type>
{
private:
    int maxStackSize;
    int stackTop;
    Type *list;
public:
/***
 Other methods ...

**/
void reverseStack(stackType<Type>& otherStack)
{

    int count = 0;
    otherStack.list = new Type[maxStackSize]; // why does this WORK!!! its private
    otherStack.stackTop = 0; // why does this WORK!!! its private

    //copy otherStack into this stack. 
    for (int j = stackTop - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        otherStack.push(list[j]);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Here is the main loop with the calls.

```
stackType<int> stack1(50);
stackType<int> stack2(50);

stack1.initializeStack();
stack1.push(1);
stack1.push(2);
stack1.push(3);
stack1.push(4);
stack1.push(5);
stack1.reverseStack(stack2);
```

So what's going on with this in C++ cause in Java, PHP, Python(mangled naming) and other OOD would not allow this.

Comment: *would not allow this* - can you be more specific about what *this* is? Also your code declares `stackADT` but uses `stackType`. Which is it?

Comment: I said that's the interface, 

template <class Type>
class stackType : public stackADT<Type>
{
private......

it extends

Comment: I see. It's a good idea to post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) so that we have the whole picture. As it stands, your question doesn't describe the relationship between `stackADT` and `stackType`, which makes it confusing.

Comment: make the reverseStack a friendly method for stackADT

Comment: Ok I added the extra info, but you guys are late to the game... someone smart enough already answered it... so thanks for trying

Comment: You've got your member variables declared twice. You don't need (or want) those in `stackADT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are confused what private actually does because this would also work in Java.

Private means that instances of other classes (or no classes, meaning functions) can't change/call/invoke/... that member/method. The important part here is that it says **other classes**. Instances of the same class can change/call/invoke/... private members/methods.

Comment: So any other instance of the class can call other instance's private methods or variables?

Answer (score 0):

As shown, it wouldn’t compile.

The point is that the function `reverseStack` is supposed to be a *member* method instead, so it should start with:
`void stackADT::reverseStack(stackType<Type>& otherStack)`
As a member method, it has access to `private` variables.